# AngularJS ngOptions directive to wait for render

Tags: angularjs, directive, ng-options

I've got select list generated with ngOptions in my template.

```
<select class="dropdown" ng-options="price.weight for price in pricelist | unique: 'weight'" ng-model="weightModel" ng-change="updateWeight()" load-select="ngRepeatFinished"></select>
```

I use this directive to wait theese lists to be rendered

```
.directive('loadSelect', function($timeout){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout(function() {
            scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
        });
        }
    }
})
```

The Idea is to run some js after select lists are full rendered

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
            console.log('rendered')
              $('.dropdown')
                .dropdown({
                    transition: 'drop'
                })
            ;
        });
```

Sometimes it works, bot sometimes does not. It works about 3 times of 5. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT. Now I've discovered, that if my console in browser is closed, it does not work at all (

Comment: What exactly is your issue? What are you trying to accomplish? What is the intended outcome? You need to provide more information.

Comment: so what youre looking for, is not waiting for the element to be rendered, but the options to be populated, right?

Comment: yep, I want select element to have oll options inside it, as I aply js to it

Comment: It would be best to see the rest of your code, but for a quick fix, you could add ng-if='pricelist' to the select. This will make the element not  render until the options are populated

Comment: ng-if='pricelist' solves the probleb. You've made my day, thnx )